# SQL query not returning expected date time range

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on a query that I hope to be able to use to query against a database for a specific range of time on a specific date. If I query for a full day of data I get the correct data returned. One row per hour of data available (0 - 23).

```
WHERE Documents.CreationTime BETWEEN '2014-10-01 00:00:00.000' AND '2014-10-01 23:59:59.999'
```

If I attempt to query for a portion of the day, the results are unusual.

```
WHERE Documents.CreationTime BETWEEN '2014-10-01 00:00:00.000' AND '2014-10-01 06:00:00.000'
```

Part day query returns: (Note the hours jump from 0 to 19)

```
    Hours   Faxes   Good Page Count
    0         3       4
    19       15      58
    20        4       9
    21        8      42
    22        2       4
    23        4      12
```

Here is my reduced query I created to try and resolve the issue.

```
SELECT DATEPART(hour, DATEADD(HH, - DATEDIFF(Hour, GETDATE(), GETUTCDATE()), Documents.CreationTime)) AS Hours
    ,COUNT(*) AS Faxes
    ,SUM(goodpagecount) AS [Good Page Count]
FROM Documents
JOIN Users
    ON Documents.OwnerID = Users.handle
JOIN Groups
    ON Users.GroupID = Groups.handle
JOIN History
    ON History.OWNER = Documents.handle
JOIN HistoryTRX
    ON History.handle = HistoryTRX.handle
WHERE Documents.CreationTime BETWEEN '2014-10-01 00:00:00.000'
        AND '2014-10-01 06:00:00.000'
GROUP BY DATEPART(hour, DATEADD(HH, - DATEDIFF(Hour, GETDATE(), GETUTCDATE()), Documents.CreationTime))
ORDER BY DATEPART(hour, DATEADD(HH, - DATEDIFF(Hour, GETDATE(), GETUTCDATE()), Documents.CreationTime))
```

Any suggestions as to what I am missing or improvements?

EDIT- More details
The "Documents.CreationTime" is in UTC. I am looking to have the "Hours" column correspond to local time. In this case UTC -5 as of this entry.

Comment: What's the result of `DATEDIFF(Hour,GETDATE(),GETUTCDATE())` for you?. Also, don't use `BETWEEN` in this case for filtering a `DATETIME`, instead of `BETWEEN '2014-10-01 00:00:00.000' AND '2014-10-01 23:59:59.999'` use `col >= '20141001' AND col < '20141002'`

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure what your question is. What is the issue and what improvements do you want?

Comment: @AndriyM The problem is that the filter suggests times from `0` till `5`, but the results are times from `19` till `0`. This is because of the "correction" that's being made on the `SELECT` (`-DATEDIFF(Hour,GETDATE(),GETUTCDATE())`). That correction is [substracting 5 hours](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26344434/sql-query-not-returning-expected-date-time-range#comment41351049_26344607) to the results, hence giving different results than expected

Comment: @gritts All right, some more details are needed. Is `Documents.CreationTime` UTC or local time? When you specify the boundaries, are they supposed to be UTC or local time? My guess is you would like the input and the output to be consistent (both to be either UTC or local time) but I'm not sure, and I'm also not sure if that is the actual problem you are trying to solve with this question.

Comment: @AndriyM, the Documents.CreationTime is recorded in UTC. I am attempting to output in local time to save confusion in the final report to be created.

Comment: Well, what is your issue with the query then? It seems to do exactly what you want, i.e. it outputs hourly results in local time, as far as I can see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on suggestions provided in response to my question, I came up with the following new query:

```
SELECT  DATEPART(hour, DATEADD(HH,-DATEDIFF(Hour,GETDATE(),GETUTCDATE()),Documents.CreationTime)) AS Hours ,COUNT(*) AS Faxes,SUM(goodpagecount) AS [Good Page Count]
FROM Documents
JOIN Users ON Documents.OwnerID=Users.handle
JOIN Groups ON Users.GroupID=Groups.handle
JOIN History ON History.Owner=Documents.handle
JOIN HistoryTRX ON History.handle=HistoryTRX.handle
WHERE DATEADD(HH,-DATEDIFF(Hour,GETDATE(),GETUTCDATE()),Documents.CreationTime) >= '2014-10-01 00:00:00.000' and DATEADD(HH,-DATEDIFF(Hour,GETDATE(),GETUTCDATE()),Documents.CreationTime) <= '2014-10-03 08:00:00.000'
GROUP BY  DATEPART(hour, DATEADD(HH,-DATEDIFF(Hour,GETDATE(),GETUTCDATE()),Documents.CreationTime))
ORDER BY  DATEPART(hour, DATEADD(HH,-DATEDIFF(Hour,GETDATE(),GETUTCDATE()),Documents.CreationTime))
```

My changes are to the "WHERE" statement by adding my UTC compensation. The "WHERE" now matches the "SELECT".

Before:

```
WHERE Documents.CreationTime >= '2014-10-01 00:00:00.000' and Documents.CreationTime <= '2014-10-03 08:00:00.000'
```

After:

```
WHERE DATEADD(HH,-DATEDIFF(Hour,GETDATE(),GETUTCDATE()),Documents.CreationTime) >= '2014-10-01 00:00:00.000' and DATEADD(HH,-DATEDIFF(Hour,GETDATE(),GETUTCDATE()),Documents.CreationTime) <= '2014-10-03 08:00:00.000'
```

Also removed the BETWEEN keyword as it may not be as precise for results as I would like.

The results now look like:

```
    Hours   Faxes   Good Page Count
      0       3      4
      1       5      9
      3       9     50
      4       8     16
      5      14     40
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using the DATEADD function in your where clause:

```
WHERE Documents.CreationTime >= '20141001' AND Documents.CreationTime <= DATEADD(HOUR,6,'20141001')
```

Interesting Blog on the comment made by Lamak written by Aaron Bertrand :

- [What do BETWEEN and the devil have in common?](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)

Comment: I adjusted what you suggested to read "WHERE Documents.CreationTime >= '2014-10-01 00:00:00.000' and Documents.CreationTime <= DATEADD(HH,6,'2014-10-01 00:00:00.000')" but the results were the same.

Comment: @gritts Well, let us help you, can you answer what's the result that you get when you do `DATEDIFF(Hour,GETDATE(),GETUTCDATE())`?

Comment: Sure, did not mean to sound gruff... Using "SELECT DATEDIFF(Hour,GETDATE(),GETUTCDATE())" I get the result of "5"

Comment: @gritts Well, then, that explain your results, doesn't it?. So, you have results from the hours `0` till `5` (this because of your filter). Then, you are substracting 5 hours to those results (this from your `DATEADD()`. So, now your results are for hours since `19` from the day before till `0`

Comment: @Lamak, yes, it does make sense but without the UTC correction I am attempting, my returned results are off by that many hours. Perhaps my question should be how best to handle queries for items whose time is offset by UTC? Sorry, I'm not much for the inner workings but what you are pointing out is making sense.

Comment: @gritts If you want your results to be consistent, then you should apply that same correction to your filter (though if the results are actually what you are looking for, I'm not sure)